# Arranging vector x as an anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to input a vector x onto a matrix where values of x are located on the anti-diagonal of the matrix

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
ID = function(x){
  n = length(x)
  A = matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  for ( i in 1:n){
    A[i, n-i+1] = x[i]
  }
  print(A)  # Why did my code not work when I did not include this
}

Z = ID(x)
```

I was wondering why does my code not work when I do not include the print(A) within the function. When I don't include Print(A), my z turns out to be NULL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `return` statement is not encountered before the end of the function body, then the function returns the value of the last "top level" expression. When you exclude `print(A)`, the last top level expression is the `for` call, which returns `NULL` invisibly, as documented in `` ?`for` ``.

I would modify your function in three ways:

- Replace `matrix(0, n, n)` with `matrix(vector(typeof(x), n * n), n, n)` so that the type of the matrix result matches the type of the vector argument.
- Replace the `for` loop with a vectorized subassignment.
- Replace `print(A)` with `A` so that `print(ID(x))` doesn't print the matrix twice.

Hence my version of your function would look something like this:

```r
antidiag <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    A <- matrix(vector(typeof(x), n * n), n, n)
    if (n > 0L) {
        A[cbind(n:1, 1:n)] <- x
    }
    A
}

antidiag(1:4)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    0    4
## [2,]    0    0    3    0
## [3,]    0    2    0    0
## [4,]    1    0    0    0

antidiag(1:4 > 0L)
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
## [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

antidiag(letters[1:4])
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,] ""   ""   ""   "d" 
## [2,] ""   ""   "c"  ""  
## [3,] ""   "b"  ""   ""  
## [4,] "a"  ""   ""   ""
```

Comment: How come when I do Z = ID(x) and then print (z), it still shows NULL; I am just testing out different methods.

Comment: `z` is not the same as `Z`...

Answer (score 0):

I would do this without a loop -

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)

ID = function(x){
  n = length(x)
  A = matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  diag(A[nrow(A):1, ]) <- x
  A
}
ID(x)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    5
#[2,]    0    0    0    4    0
#[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
#[4,]    0    2    0    0    0
#[5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```